# Best way to package Workflow for Sites 9.1?

Tags: workflow, sites-9.1, add-on

We can group and package extensions to Tridion Sites by creating an [Add-on](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/705437/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/add-ons), which is a ZIP file containing configuration and related code.

I can see the documentation for the [extension types](https://docs.sdl.com/783502/705488/sdl-tridion-sites-9-1/extension-types), in this case for Sites 9.1. Workflow Process Definitions and related (C#) code aren't in the list.

**To be sure, is it possible to deploy a Workflow Process Definition and/or related code as an Add-on?**

I *think* the current approach for workflow would be to:

1. Create and upload the **Workflow Process Definition** via the Content Manager Explorer
2. Set related Workflow code in the automated activities or decisions as "external" and **separately use `TCMUPload` to load related C# dlls** to the Content Manager.
3. Optionally **automate dll deployment to DEV** through your build configuration/setup in your IDE (e.g. Visual Studio).

In short, I think Process Definitions are managed in the Content Manager Explorer Workflow screen while workflow code is uploaded with the `TCMUpload` script. **Is this the current practice and am I missing anything?**

Comment: 1. You mean upload Workflow "Process" Definition? The steps you describe seem correct to me - in the same way there's no add-on extension type for TBBs.

Comment: Oops, yes that was a typo. Fixed. Feel free to answer the same as your comment, noting that Workflow code works like TBBs, and I'll accept!